# How to use sed within vim editor to replace a pattern?

Tags: vim, sed, nrpe

I have the next code:

```
command[check_ping]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ping -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
command[check_filemtime]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_filemtime $ARG1$
command[check_iostat]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_iostat $ARG1$ $ARG2$
command[check_open_files]=perl /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_open_files.pl -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
command[check_itai]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/itai
command[check_mem]=perl /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mem.pl -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$_
command[check_uptime]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_uptime
command[check_ifstatus]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ifstatus -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
command[check_local_load]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_load -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
command[check_local_disk]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p $ARG3$
```

From within vim editor, I'd like to add an escaping char `"\"` before each `$ARG` argument so I tried this command:
`:81,129!sed -e "/\<\$A/\<\\$A"`, but what happens is that these lines (81-129) disappear and the error from the `sed` command is written in line #81, what am I doing wrong?
81-129 are the relevant line numbers in the file

Comment: did you want to do the operation only on the lines from `81 to 129`?

Comment: Why are you using sed instead of simply `:s/find/replace/g`?

Comment: Lack of knowledge I guess :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vim` can do the regex searching & replacing. So, you do not need to use external tool like `sed`. You can simply write as,

```
:81,129s/ \$ARG/ \\$ARG/g
```

Comment: Nah, no `-i`; The `!` command filters, i.e. sends to stdin and reads from stdout.